# How can I show country icons in the select list provided by the countries module on the edit page?

Tags: forms

I am using the 2.x series of the [Countries](http://drupal.org/project/countries) and [Country Icons](http://drupal.org/project/countryicons) modules.  They are both installed properly on my site.

I have a country field called "Nationality" on the user profile page.  I would like to show the flags in the drop-down list (the select widget) when users are editing their profiles.

There is [an example of how to show countryicons with user info](http://drupal.org/node/1280164) in the Country Icons documentation but this is for displayed comments, not an edit form.

Basically, what I want is to give the look that the [Language Switcher Dropdown](http://drupal.org/project/lang_dropdown) module does (screenshot on module page), but for a country field.

Comment: looks like it requires some jquery magic. You could add a feature request for country_icons module and point them to the language switcher module. Btw, would love to chat with you about your site, we seem to have similar features on our sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following MotoTribe's suggestion, I [filed a feature request](http://drupal.org/node/1621694) which is already in progress.  Exciting!